# Web browser that can be installed on command line ubuntu 16.4

Tags: apache2, localhost

I have successfully installed & tested **Command line Ubuntu** 16.4 on my laptop. I'm now setting up Apache2 server(downloaded while installing Ubuntu installation). I have configured the necessary config files for local testing a website (Test.com) on Apache2 server. But I don't know how I can test the Apache2 server locally? Do I install a browser (say firefox) on the same machine (as commandline ubuntu machine) to test it? If yes, then how?

Any prompt response with **simple instructions** will be highly appreciated.

Comment: If you only have access to the CLI (i.e. no GUI), there's several textmode browsers you can try, see [What is the best text-mode browser?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/40350/what-is-the-best-text-mode-browser). You can install any of these by typing `sudo apt-get install <name>`. Alternatively, for basic testing, you can use `curl` to get what the server serves as plaintext, e.g. `curl http://127.0.0.1`.

Comment: Thanks Jonas. Before I can install lynx I have to get access to internet. I assumed that when I installed my ubuntu 16.4.3 via wireless network it would be automatically enabled for internet access. That doesn't seem to the case. So I have to enable my wireless network so that I can get past the error "Temporary failure resolving us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/". The enabling of my wireless interface appears to be a long winded process. And it is taking time to set set it up!!!